# Android: How to login into my app by using twitter (not with the help of web view or browser)

Tags: android, twitter, authentication

Hi I'm successfully logging into my app by using twitter.

For code [click here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7i8jm172rsu9pzb/AAC2Xf1XJTlZ59c5tg3w4363a?dl=0)

By using this code I'm redirecting to twitter web site in default browser and then allowing user to login. But my requirement is, if user installed twitter app in device, I don't want to redirect him/her to twitter web site and i want to get basic information of particular user from installed twitter app. If there is no twitter app installed means, I want to redirect him to twitter in default browser. For this requirement i saw all other examples in internet but no one implemented like this